# restoring database from .frm & .ibd

Tags: wordpress, database-restore, wordpress-database

I have a WordPress site hosted on a Linux server. I need desperate help restoring my database. I managed to salvage the phpmyadmin folder from the server and the following folders:

"var/lib/mysql/performance_schema"
"var/lib/mysql/sys"
"var/lib/mysql/wordpress"
"var/lib/mysql/mysql"

I might be able to recover other files if you think are important to the process.

Can anyone help me build the database from these files?

I found resources online about restoring from mariadb-dump but it was too confusing and not detailed enough. I also tried loading up scripts into MySQL while the tables were created, I did not know how to proceed thereafter.

I tried desperately to access Https://my-ip/phpmyadmin but it would not allow me in. I'm too afraid to try anything at this point fearing that I might further screw things up.

Thank you...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi Hardik, I followed the instructions on this website. While the tables were created in phpmyadmin, but once I copied the .ibd I got Schema Mismatch error which I tried to fix to no avai. https://mgfn.net/how-to-restore-wordpress-database-from-frm-ibd-files-step-by-step/